# Create bins dynamically in dataframe with by using breaks & quantiles fails?

Tags: r, dataframe, binning

EDIT:
I have made a mistake in my previous code that I shared. I replaced the "bins" with "b" but missed one...

I also use the correct data.frame now (y instead of the original df.score)

NEW code:

```
# some data
x <- runif(1000)
x2 <- rnorm(1000)
y <- data.frame(x,x2)
# we want to bin the dataframe y acording to values in x into b bins
b = 10
bins=10

# we create breaks in several ways
breaks=unique(quantile(x, probs=seq.int(0,1, by=1/b)))
breaks=unique(quantile(y$x, probs=seq.int(0,1, length.out=b+1)))

# now to the question
# this wokrs
y$b <- with(y, cut(x, breaks=unique(quantile(x, probs=seq.int(0,1, length.out=11))), include.lowest=TRUE))
table(y$b)
# this works too
y$b2 <- with(y, cut(x, breaks=unique(quantile(x, probs=seq.int(0,1, length.out=(bins+1)))), include.lowest=TRUE))
table(y$b2)
# this does not work
y$b3 <- with(y, cut(x, breaks=unique(quantile(x, probs=seq.int(0,1, length.out=(b+1)))), include.lowest=TRUE))
```

Error in seq.int(0, 1, length.out = (b + 1)) : 
  'length.out' must be a non-negative number
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(b, 1) : + not meaningful for factors

Now if I split the code up there is no issue !!!

```
brks=unique(quantile(x, probs=seq.int(0,1, length.out=(b + 1))))
y$b3 <- with(y, cut(x, breaks=brks, include.lowest=TRUE))
```

I am lost here...

This is part of more dynamic code, knitred together based on details in the data set.

So I want to create bins on the fly and report on them. The code works now but I do not understand why when I use the word "bins" the code works and when using the "b" it fails...?

---

OLD from here
I need to add bins dynamically to a dataframe so I can report on them later.

```
# some data
x <- runif(1000)
x2 <- rnorm(1000)
y <- data.frame(x,x2)
# we want to bin the dataframe y acording to values in x into b bins
b = 10

# we create breaks in several ways
breaks=unique(quantile(x, probs=seq.int(0,1, by=1/b)))
breaks=unique(quantile(y$x, probs=seq.int(0,1, length.out=b+1)))

# now to question
# this works

y$bins <- with(df.score, cut(x, breaks=unique(quantile(Pchurn, probs=seq.int(0,1, length.out=11))), include.lowest=TRUE))
table(y$bins)
```

So if I want to do the exact same using the bin var directly it fails:

```
# this does not work
y$bins <- with(df.score, cut(x, breaks=unique(quantile(Pchurn, probs=seq.int(0,1, length.out=bins+1))), include.lowest=TRUE))


Error in seq.int(0, 1, length.out = (bins + 1)) : 
  'length.out' must be a non-negative number
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(bins, 1) : + not meaningful for factors
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Example's not reproducible.

Comment: Do you have a column `bins` in your `df.score`? IMHO you want to use `length.out=b+1` instead of `length.out=bins+1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this (substituting `b` for `bins` in the length parameter calc just below "#this does not work":

```
y$bins <- with(df.score, cut(x, 
                    breaks=unique(quantile(Pchurn, 
                                         probs=seq.int(0,1, length.out=b+1))), 
                    include.lowest=TRUE))
```

Hard to test without a score variable and a more complete description of the goals, but at least the code does not throw an error with this in the workspace.

```
 df.score=data.frame(Pchurn=rnorm(100), x=rnorm(100))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for replies, I see there was a mistake in my example. I did not replace all "bins" with "b" and this seems to solve the problem.Strange the word bins seems to mean something else then the number I asigned to it?

Comment: You did not have a an object named 'bins' when I looked at the question earlier. You are probably confusing yourself by having column names that are the same as are being used as object names. That will cause confusion similar to the problems with using the `attach` function.

Comment: I are right I confused myself, but now I restarted R session cleared the workspace but still the above throws the error. Only on example b3...

Comment: Right. Now you have a column named 'b' and an object named 'b' and because you are using `with(y, ...)` the R interpreter finds a vector value for the length.out parameter before it finds the length-1 object in the workspace and throws an error. STOP USING THE SAME NAMES FOR OBJECTS AND COLUMNS!